# Angular simple nested Iteration

Tags: arrays, json, angular, nested, iteration

My JSON Data

```
    [
    {"type":"select","label":"Company Name",
        "options":{"ck_i1":"Comp 1","ck_i2":"Comp 2","ck_i3":"Comp 3","ck_i4":"Comp 4"}
    }
    ,   
    {"type":"text","label":"Proposed Date","effectiveDate": "" }
    ,
    {"type":"text","label":"Named Indivdual","namedIndividual": "" }
    ,
    {"type":"text","label":"Date of Birth","dob": "" }
    ]
```

Template

```
       <li *ngFor="let item of items">
            {{item}}
          <ul *ngFor="let child of item">
            {{ child.label  }}
          </ul>
         </li>
```

Component TS

```
      items = [];
        this.items = Array.of(this.jsonData);
```

The first iteration works fine and displays the `JSON`. But the second iteration `child.label` throws an error

> type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Any clue what might be causing this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn’t because item represents  {"type":"select","label":"Company Name",
    "options":{"ck_i1":"Comp 1","ck_i2":"Comp 2","ck_i3":"Comp 3","ck_i4":"Comp 4"}
} which is not an iterative array?

Comment: Hi! In stackblitz your code is working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqxouk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you Bartosz. When I hard code the array it works. But when the data comes from DB, I get the below error.... type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: My Console log of the object from the data base. It looks good. But couldnt get the data. [{"type": "select","label": "Insurance DB Company Name","options": { "ck_i1": "Comp 1", "ck_i2": "Comp 2","ck_i3": "Comp 3","ck_i4": "Comp 4"}},{"type": "text","label": "Proposed Effective Date","effectiveDate": ""},{"type": "text","label": "Named Indivdual","namedIndividual": ""}]

Comment: Initially I had the code to convert the string to JSON only once. Apparently, I have to convert even the inner nested element. Good to go. Thank you for you support. Just in case.. I used JSON.parse() on inner element too.